# in spring boot, what's better? using multiple repositories in one service or using multiple services in one controller?

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest, service, repository

I am trying to make this rest endpoint : `/api/Offers/{offerId}/comments`, what is better in design view?

- using `CommentRepository` and `OfferRepository` inside `OfferService`
  OR
- using `CommentService` and `OfferService` inside `OfferController`

It is sort of specific to general issue, I don't know what is most recommended approach!

Answer (score 0):

I would pick the second variant:

using CommentService and OfferService inside OfferController

There is no special reason for that, but for me its clearer, other than the repositories. (Only my Opinion)